# How to wrap every element from the_content in separate divs?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am new to wordPress theme development, and I've been trying to get all of the elements of a single page post to be wrapped in separate divs. It is my understanding that the_content will just display whatever is in the single page, so I am not able to loop through the elements. Am I wrong in trying to use the_content here? Should I use get_the_content?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just click on the 'text' tab on the right hand corner of the editor and input your div tags manually. [See here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fRI21.png)

Comment: Now that you mention it, that's probably an easier way than what I had in mind, thanks!